# Getting Contacts from folders in "Other Contacts"

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, contacts

I've got a code snippet that works.

```
Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim ContactFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set Session = Application.Session

Set ContactFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
```

It sets ContactFolder as an Outlook.Folder type but it does this by using some default framework, olFolderContacts.

I would like to set a custom folder as the ContactFolder variable. Specifically, they are in Other Contacts. I've seen some methods on the MSDN involving **entryID** but I haven't been able to get the entryID of my custom contact folders.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is a subfolder of the Contacts folder:

```
set subFolder = ContactFolder.Folders("My other contacts")
```

If it is on the same level as the Contacts folder:

```
set subFolder = ContactFolder.Parent.Folders("My other contacts")
```